# Generate XML from XPages content in Lotus Domino

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

Please, tell me - how i can create XML from content of the fields on XPage, on button click (in Lotus Domino 9)?
Thanks in advance for the information.

Now i'm trying to create an agent that will do this, but i still don't understand - how to assign the execution of this agent to a button

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very high level. What have you tried so far that we can comment on? With XPages and Java you have lots of options for generating XML.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is an [XAgent](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2008/12/xagents-web-agents-xpages-style.html), a piece of code you can trigger with a link or wire it to an XPages button. To simplify your XML creation, you can use the [SimpleXMLDoc](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2020/04/simplexmldoc-revisited.html) class that ensures you create valid XML (Don't try to use String operations, they are a pain for XML).